# how to delete an empty list in an array object in python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, object, filter

I have this as data

```
store_list = {
    "ECG 12D":[],
    "ETT Adulte":[
                    {"series":"Série sans label","modality":"OT","count":48},
                    {"series":"Série sans label","modality":"SR","count":47},
                    {"series":"Série sans label","modality":"ETT","count":43}
                ]
    }
```

I would like to know how to remove ECG12D in my data for example ?
Get this !

```
store_list = {
    "ETT Adulte":[
                    {"series":"Série sans label","modality":"OT","count":48},
                    {"series":"Série sans label","modality":"SR","count":47},
                    {"series":"Série sans label","modality":"US","count":43}
                ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{k: v for k, v in store_list.items() if v}
```

**UPDATE:**

Somebody suggested edit:

```
{k: v for k, v in store_list.items() if v == []}
```

It's actually unnecessary, because python interprets empty list as False value.

And also if you don't want to use syntax sugar, the better way, as for me, will be:

```
{k: v for k, v in store_list.items() if len(v) > 0}
```